# Will an EPS saved in Illustrator CC open in any Illustrator version?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-format, eps

If I save a EPS vector file in Illustrator CC version will it open up in any Illustrator version (e.g. CS4, CS5, CS6)? Or do I need to save separate EPS files for each version of Illustrator?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by open. I mean illustrator will even open newer versions of AI files as PDF once you remove the AI version tags from the file (assuming PDF compatibility wasn't turned off). But what happens to features it does not know is a different matter. Same would obviously happen also in saving to older versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general... it may open, but will present a warning for legacy versions -- something along the lines of *"This file was generated with a newer version of Illustrator. Some object may not appear correctly."*

Then it often opens with **objects completely missing or flattened** and may even rasterize objects in some instances.

If you want a solid EPS to open in any version of Illustrator, think **oldest version**. Then save to *that* version EPS format. Anything *newer* will open the old format EPS fine.  So if you want to ensure AICS4 compatibility, save to an AICS4 EPS format (there is that option when you save an EPS). Then anything newer than CS4 will open the EPS without an issue.

This often means you need to construct the EPS with the limitations of the old version in mind. For example, saving to Illustrator 8 EPS was standard for many, many years, and is still fairly common. But to properly save to AI8 EPS, you need to remove **all** transparency and blend modes from the artwork.

Also note that "CC" isn't *necessarily* enough of a discriminating factor. EPS files from CC2017 may still be  problem if opened in CC2014.

**Small Tip:** If you *are* saving to a legacy version EPS, *always* retain the original .ai file and work on that, not the EPS. In addition, it's really wise to open the saved EPS and see how things are constructed. There are *often* some minor changes you can make in the original file which will make the legacy EPS either less complex or to improve overall construction within the EPS format - things like, manually flattening a specific part of artwork, or expanding a stroke.. minor things that are just *specifically* so the EPS is better constructed. I *never* save a legacy EPS without then opening it to see how the art has been reconstructed. I then go *back to the original .ai file* to make any changes and re-save a copy as an EPS. I don't make any changes in the EPS itself.